# ASP.NET - The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

estoy tratando de hacer un método que devuelve un `json` , pero cuando lo llamo me tira este error.

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Es algo inusual, porque tengo otros método iguales pero llamando a otras tablas y funciona muy bien.

```
  [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult EvaCualitSecuencial_PREGUNTAS_ListJson()
    {


        using (BD_SISTEMA_INTEGRALEntities db = new BD_SISTEMA_INTEGRALEntities())
        {
            var preguntas = db.EvaluacionCualitativadeGrupoComunalSecuencial_Preguntas.ToList<EvaluacionCualitativadeGrupoComunalSecuencial_Preguntas>();

            return Json(preguntas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Alguien podría darme un poco de ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema está en la forma de recuperar los datos de tu **DbContext**.

Es el error "clásico" que ocurre por lo que se llama **LazyLoading**. Intentas recuperar un objeto que crea un bucle infinito (por las propiedades de navegación) al generar el JSON.

Además, el `using()` realiza un `Dispose` del **DbContext** antes de caer en un error mas grave.

En tu `DbContext`, deshabilita el **LazyLoading** de la siguiente manera, y te funcionará:

```
public class TuContexto : DbContext 
{ 
   public TuContexto() 
   { 
       this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
   } 
}
```